# Why can't we increase size of ArrayList object returned by asList()?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I was going through the implementation of `Arrays.asList()`.If we try to change the size of the array through `List(I)` specific methods then RE: `UnsupportedException` is obtained.
Implementation -

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

According to the above implementation, as an `ArrayList` object is returned by `asList`, why can't we change the size of returned `List` object?

Specifically, what prevents one from changing the size of the returned `ArrayList` object?

Any leads would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact overload being used? It has multiple iirc.

Comment: Yup, that is what is given in java.util.Arrays;

Comment: Here's the return I see when I look at the source: `return new Arrays.ArrayList(a)`. It's not a normal ArrayList.

Comment: It's a different class that just happens to also be called `ArrayList`.

Comment: `System.out.println(asList().getClass())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList()` is partially *immutable*. Some mutation operations are implemented, others aren't. Basically, all operations that write through to the underlying array are implemented. Operations that would require reallocating a new array are not implemented. `set()` for example is implemented, `add()` isn't. If you need a proper `List` mutable in all aspects:

```
List<T> myList = asList(v1, v2, v3); // Immutable
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>(asList(v1, v2, v3)); // Mutable
```

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList()` is not a "normal" `(java.util.)ArrayList`. A normal `ArrayList` can grow by re-allocating its backing array, which means it is a proper `List` backed by an array but with all `List` features available.

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList()` is a "`List` view" on the original array. It cannot grow because that would lose the link to the original array. The following code demonstrates this:

```
String[] data = { "foo", "bar" };
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(data);
System.err.println(values); // [foo, bar]
data[0] = "buzz";
values.set(1, "quak");
System.err.println(values); // [buzz, quak]
System.err.println(Arrays.toString(data)); // [buzz, quak]
```

Comment: It is not mutable. Calling `set()` will throw an exception.

Comment: I take it back, it's mutable. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize it's that inconsistent.

Comment: Ya. I was looking here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3845

Comment: It's not inconsistent. The `Arrays.asList` documentation says it "_returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array_".  The `add` and `remove` methods inherently require a variable-sized list. The reason you can use `set` (and `get`) is because it's just like accessing an array via an index, except instead of an array it's a `List`. This is somewhat explained by `AbstractList`: "_To implement a modifiable list, [you] must additionally override the set(int, E) method [. . .] If the list is variable-size [you] must additionally override the add(int, E) and remove(int) methods._".

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your pointers, I've updated the answer accordingly.